# In jQuery how can I do an addClass followed by a fadeout?

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a class which renders an element a particular color and then fade out that color back to the original.  I thought the following would work (btn-warning changes the element to the color I want)

```
$('.myclass').addClass('btn-warning');
$('.myclass .btn-warning').fadeOut();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) fades out the entire element. It doesn't gradually remove a class. For that, use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). If it's a color (not a numeric property) that you want to animate, you'll need [some jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/) as well.

```
$('.myclass')
    .addClass('btn-warning')
    .animate({color: '#000000'}, 600);
```

Comment: Yup. The author might want to consider changing the background colour to red or yellow, then animating (fading out) that background colour.

Comment: $('.myclass').css("background-color", "red").animate({ "background-color" : "#fff" }, 5000);

Answer (score 2):

You can fade from one class to another with jQueryUI.  But first we need to address a problem with your selector.  You need to remove the space from your selector:

```
$('.myclass.btn-warning')
```

The space tells jQuery you are looking for a descendent element.  Removing the space indicates the target element should have *both* classes.

To transition back to the previous colors, `.fadeOut()` won't work.  It fades out an element until it is hidden.  Instead, [include jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/download)<sup>*</sup> and use `.removeClass()`.  [jQueryUI extends `.removeClass()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/removeClass/) so that if you pass a `duration` parameter, it will transition from the class instead of removing it immediately.

```
$('.myclass').addClass('btn-warning');
$('.myclass.btn-warning').removeClass('btn-warning', 2000);
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('btn-warning').removeClass('btn-warning', 2000);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/8afDP/

---

<sup>*</sup> Actually, all you need for this is jQueryUI Effects Core.  On [the download page](http://jqueryui.com/download), click "Deselect all components", then scroll down to "Effects" and select "Effects Core".  Then click the "Download" button.

**Demo with only jQueryUI Effects Core:** http://jsfiddle.net/8afDP/1/

Answer (score 1):

you can chain it like this:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('btn-warning').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

Origin of the bug:

You should remove an extra space in the second selector, as it's the same element with .myclass that gets an extra .btn-warning class:

```
$('.myclass').addClass('btn-warning');
$('.myclass.btn-warning').fadeOut();
```

Or you can chain .addClass() and .fadeOut() as it'll act on the same element.